# Biblatex-apa: problem with long dates in Spanish

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, spanish

I am using the latest version of `biblatex-apa` with the `spanish-apa.lbx` file for localisation and there seems to be a problem with long dates with the same month but different days. For example,

2019-03-27/2019-04-29 is correctly rendered as "(2019, 27 de marzo-29 de abril)"

but

2019-03-27/2019-03-29 is rendered as "(2019, 27 de marzo-)" instead of "(2019, 27-29 de marzo)".

I have tried also with Galician (`galician-apa.lbx`), which has the same kind of date formats as Spanish, with the same results.

Many thanks in advance for any hints on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you edit your question to show a minimal document and sample `.bib` file entry(s) that show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (American) date format in `biblatex-apa` does not particularly lend itself to `dd. mm. yyyy` date formats, so many other languages needs special treatment.

Please try the following (based on code from `ngerman-apa.lbx`)

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \def\urldatecomma{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalong#1#2#3{%
    % As per 10.1, Articles only have year
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{article}}
                 and not test {\ifkeyword{nonacademic}} }
      {\clearfield{labelmonth}%
       \clearfield{labelday}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldbibstring{#1}{\biblcstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\thefield{#1}}%
       \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{#3}} and test {\iffieldundef{#2}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}
         {}
         {\addspace de\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongextra#1#2#3{%
    % As per 10.1, Articles only have year
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{article}}
                 and not test {\ifkeyword{nonacademic}} }
      {\clearfield{labelmonth}%
       \clearfield{labelday}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldbibstring{#1}{\biblcstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\thefield{#1}}%
       \printfield{extradate}%
       \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{#3}} and test {\iffieldundef{#2}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}
         {}
         {\addspace de\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {}%
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateapalongmdy#1#2#3{%
    % As per 10.1, Articles only have year
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{article}}
                 and not test {\ifkeyword{nonacademic}} }
      {\clearfield{labelmonth}%
       \clearfield{labelday}}
      {}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}%
      {}%
      {el\addspace\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}%
      {\addspace{en}\addspace}%
      {\iffieldundef{#3}%
        {en\addspace}%
        {\addspace{de}\addspace}%
       \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}{\addspace{de}\addspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}%
      {}%
      {\iffieldundef{#2}%
        {}%
        {\addspace}%
       \thefield{#1}}}%
  \def\apa@lbx@es@mkdaterangeapalong#1{%
    \begingroup
      \blx@metadateinfo{#1}%
      \iffieldundef{#1year}{}
        {\datecircaprint
         \ifstrequal{#1}{url}% URL dates are unlikely to be BCE ...
           {\printtext{%
               \iffieldsequal{#1year}{#1endyear}
                 {\iffieldsequal{#1month}{#1endmonth}
                    {\mkbibdateapalongmdy{}{}{#1day}}
                    {\mkbibdateapalongmdy{}{#1month}{#1day}}}
                 {\mkbibdateapalongmdy{#1year}{#1month}{#1day}}%
               \iffieldundef{#1endyear}%
                 {}%
                 {\iffieldequalstr{#1endyear}{}% open-ended range?
                   {\mbox{\bibdatedash}}
                   {\bibdatedash%
                    \mkbibdateapalongmdy{#1endyear}{#1endmonth}{#1endday}}}%
               \dateuncertainprint}}
           {\printtext{%
               \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldsequal{#1year}{#1endyear}}
                           and test {\iffieldsequal{#1month}{#1endmonth}}}
                 {\mkbibdateapalong{#1year}{}{#1day}}%
                 {\mkbibdateapalong{#1year}{#1month}{#1day}}%
               \dateeraprint{#1year}%
               \iffieldundef{#1endyear}%
                 {}%
                 {\iffieldequalstr{#1endyear}{}% open-ended range?
                   {\mbox{\bibdatedash}}
                   {\bibdatedash%
                    \iffieldsequal{#1year}{#1endyear}%
                      {\mkbibdateapalong{}{#1endmonth}{#1endday}}%
                      {\mkbibdateapalong{#1endyear}{#1endmonth}{#1endday}%
                     \dateeraprint{#1endyear}}}%
                 \enddateuncertainprint}}}}%
    \endgroup}%
  \def\apa@lbx@es@mkdaterangeapalongextra#1{%
    \begingroup
      \blx@metadateinfo{#1}%
      \iffieldundef{#1year}{}
        {\printtext{%
          \datecircaprint
          \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldsequal{#1year}{#1endyear}}
                           and test {\iffieldsequal{#1month}{#1endmonth}}}
            {\mkbibdateapalongextra{#1year}{}{#1day}}%
            {\mkbibdateapalongextra{#1year}{#1month}{#1day}}%
          \dateeraprint{#1year}%
          \dateuncertainprint
          \iffieldundef{#1endyear}%
            {}%
            {\iffieldequalstr{#1endyear}{}% open-ended range?
              {\mbox{\bibdatedash}}
              {\bibdatedash%
               \iffieldsequal{#1year}{#1endyear}%
                 {\mkbibdateapalongextra{}{#1endmonth}{#1endday}}
                 {\mkbibdateapalongextra{#1endyear}{#1endmonth}{#1endday}%
                  \dateeraprint{#1endyear}}}%
             \enddateuncertainprint}}}%
    \endgroup}%
  \savecommand\mkdaterangeapalong
  \savecommand\mkdaterangeapalongextra
  \def\mkdaterangeapalong{%
    \apa@lbx@es@mkdaterangeapalong}%
  \def\mkdaterangeapalongextra#1{%
    \apa@lbx@es@mkdaterangeapalongextra{#1}}%
}

\UndefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \restorecommand\mkdaterangeapalong
  \restorecommand\mkdaterangeapalongextra
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2019-03-27/2019-03-29},
}
@book{bppleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2019-03-27/2019-04-29},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
X\cite{sigfridsson,appleby,bppleby}X
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, H. (2019, 27-29 de marzo).//Bppleby, H. (2019, 27 de marzo-29 de abril).]

If the results are acceptable a plausible interpretation of what APA style should look like in Spanish (in the absence of an official translation of APA style into Spanish), you may want to open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa.

Comment: Reported in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/114 and fixed shortly afterwards.